# Java: 2D Perlin Noise Creation

Tags: persistence, frequency, noise, perlin-noise, amplitude

There are not many easy-to-follow Perlin Noise tutorials out there and certainly not in Java or 2D.  I followed [this](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm) tutorial to a point but it doesn't explain 2D noise very much at all.  I know you have to generate an array of numbers then interpolate them and everything.  My problem is that I do not know how to implement frequency, persistence, or amplitude to help affect the outcome of the numbers.  Can anyone give me some basic Perlin Noise functions or a link to a 2D Perlin Noise tutorial in Java or similar languages? Thanks!

EDIT: Can someone just briefly explain the process at least or how one implements the frequency, amplitude, and persistence to influence the generation? Please :)

Comment: What exactly is your question? There is (pseudo-)code on the page you linked which shows how to deal with perlin including persistence. You may directly translate this into any language you like.

Comment: Yes I know but I am having a problem understanding it completely. I translated it into Java completely but I am having a problem understanding exactly how it works out mathematically.  I need some sort of clear explanation of how the process works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Amplitude* and *frequency* are no free variables in the Perlin Noise generation. Instead they are parametrized by something called *persistence*.

The noise function is then the sum over several basic functions.

```
n(x) = sum( n_i(x*f_i) * a_i, i=0..N-1)
```

Each function is called *octave* and therefore numbered by the index `i`. The values `f_i` denote the frequencies and `a_i` the amplitudes. As mentioned before they are completely determined by the index `i` itself, parametrized by the *persistence* `p`:

```
f_i = 2^i
a_i = p^i
```

While each noise function `n_i(x)` is normalized for frequency `1` and amplitude `1`, the overall term `n_i(x*f_i) * a_i` now has frequency and amplitude given by the expressions above.

In other words the noise function `n(x)` is the sum of octaves where the first one has frequency `1` and amplitude `1`, the second one has frequency `2` and amplitude `p`, the third has frequency `4` and amplitude `p^2`, and so on.

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot Howard.  I scaled back to 1-Dimensional Perlin Noise for now and tried this out and it seems to work nicely.  Thanks again!

Comment: Also, when the article said that you have to add the noise together and that makes the Perlin Noise, does it mean average the noise together?

Comment: Simply adding, see the expression for `n(x)` in my answer.

Comment: I guess I am confused then because I thought I had to randomly generate multiple arrays randomly then interpolate then smooth them then put them through that n(x) equation then add them together.

Comment: I got it :DDDDDDDDDD Thanks Howard!

Comment: so persistence should be in (0-1] ? (to sum of octaves range doesn't exceed 1)